# "rsync: [generator] mknod … failed: File name too long (36)" though file & path name lengths are way shorter than 255 & 4096

Tags: rsync, ext4, qnap

On a QNAP NAS I'm trying to copy a huge backup directory from internal to an USB disk. The backup set was created using back-in-time, therefore it uses hard-links for deduplication and encfs generated file & directory names.

Running `rsync -aH --inplace /share/MD0_DATA/Backups/ /mnt/t2/B/` I receive the following errors:

###### rsync 3.0.7 (QNap stock)

`sync: mknod "/mnt/t2/B/home/8QxnYj…iE0pCkQxr" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

###### rsync 3.2.7-1a (Entware)

`rsync: [generator] mknod "/mnt/t2/B/home/8Qxn…iE0pCkQxr.26280" failed: File name too long (36)`

### Not the usual 255/4096 filename length limitation

I'm aware of the 255 bytes filename length and 4096 bytes pathname limit: But this doesn't seem to apply here in my case.

- The longest single file/directory name is only 47 characters
- The full path is only 294 characters long
- The source path is even longer!
- The source files were even created by back-in-time using the same local rsync as receiver. It's just a different server a sender.
- I can easily create and delete the exact paths using `touch` and `rm`
- Source and target are on the same system, same filesystem type (ext4), having identical mount options.

I.e., one sample path rsync reports reads: `/mnt/t2/B/home/8QxnYjsi5RSEftKDx9qGbzq3/l7ZyYNV0C,yeUTgnIuhcEQBb/ayR8ehutEqbvovJLf36EYUH1/qeJqrGaptTSMwTPoezYN2mTb/-P-gLqJGmcDYgYp6GXsLX1uaucCW-nRUlhftGIeeRotg70/vBksKzx1a3G0lIbOPqKeJEe1/Er1HTeysXU8ENmZfYkbsAPCl/XyR8ehutEqbvovJLf36EYUH1/LzHu4oEpUPIXMypAwK5XGU7L/.y-gLkcg40i8ooEbiE0pCkQxr.26280`

Any ideas on the culprit and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

At the end it turned out that both error messages are just misleading: The source file seems to be a set of backed up socket files. Only those files produced those errors.

```
srwxrwxr-x    1 ben      ben              0 Jul  4  2021 y-gLkcg40i8ooEbiE0pCkQxr
```

Interestingly the claimed target filename is `.y-gLkcg40i8ooEbiE0pCkQxr.26280`, while the actual source file misses source and prefix and is actually `y-gLkcg40i8ooEbiE0pCkQxr` (without the leading dot and the trailing number).